# Accessing and manipulating a custom elements from another js file

Tags: javascript, dom, shadow-dom

I have a custom elements with shadow root encapsulation that are displayed within a div on a webpage. I want to be able to make the corresponding div's responsive by changing some of the attributes of the custom elements(CE) displayed within them such as the text displayed within them and some CSS properties. Note, the displayed text and some other basic CSS properties for the CE's are enclosed within its constructor.

The main objective of the responsiveness is that the CE's are in a side bar (like navbar) and I'm trying to make the side bar collapsible by click of a button, thus the custom elements enclosed within it need to be responsive to that. So, when I click the button I want to be able to manipulate custom elements enclosed in the side bar (such as text and CSS).

I am able to manipulate the text and CSS while within the corresponding JS file of the custom element but I actually want to be able to do the same from outside, that is from another JS file (my main JS file). Would this be possible and if yes, could you please show me how I could do this? Also just note, I'm working with only vanilla JS.

If this is not possible, then how could I make the custom elements responsive to this situation from within their respective files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('element').addClass('hidden'); // change class
document.getElementById('element').removeClass('hidden');

document.getElementById('element').attr('hidden',false); // change attribute